# Can someone explain the Apache server directives in this config file?

Tags: apache-2.2

I want to make sure I understand what I am doing in terms of security and permissions - I have read (or attempted to read) the Apache documentation on this but it seems overly long winded and dosen't get straight to the point.

Can someone please explain what the following directives (relating to fastcgi) mean:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

particularly these keywords:

- Directory
- AllowIverride
- Options: +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
- Order
- Allow

Comment: None of them actually have anything to do with FastCGI directly.

Comment: You want someone to explain these because reading the manual was too much like hard work?

Comment: In the learning path you will have to actually read documentation. It is OK to ask things you don't quite understand, but it is very wrong to assume someone will explain things to you when you don't want to make an effort. You should thank @Alex who despite this, helped you out.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, these directives are not related to FastCGI. They are related to plain old CGI.
Since you are probably have no CGI scripts on your server, it should be safe to comment them out.

`Directory` describes properties of a content directory on server's filesystem.
`AllowOverride` describes what options can be altered by `.htaccess` file in the directory or its child directory (none in your case).
`Options` describe directory options, there can be many. `+ExecCGI` means that CGI script execution is allowed, `-MulitViews` means implicit file name conversion if file is not found is turned off and `+SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` means symlinks will be respected if file owner is the same.

`Order allow,deny` means that `Allow` directive will be processed first, then `Deny` if it is set, and `Allow from all` means that access is not restricted.